# how to change customer.value to "customer"."value" in snowflake. which removes [,],[0-9] in between the string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace procedure sp()
    returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var A= ('Customers[0].value'.replace(/\[|\]|[0-9]/g,'')).replace(/(\\w+)/g,'""');
    return A;
    $$;
```

```
call sp();
```

Comment: Please add more details so we can reproduce. Add sample data and desired results

Comment: I want the data to be transformed from "customer[0].value" to "cusotmer"."value". I am following this procedure to automate snowflake semi-structured JSON views .

Comment: I wrote a procedure to convert to the desired format. But I my code is returning customer.value instead of "customer"."value"

Comment: create or replace procedure sp()
    returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var A= 'Customers[0].value'.replace(/\[|\]|[0-9]/g,'').replace('(\w*)','"\1"');
    return A;
    $$;
call sp();

Comment: output I get after running the query
Customers.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure sp() returns VARCHAR language javascript as 
$$ 
var A = 'Customers[0].value'.replace(/(\w+)\[[0-9]].(\w+)/g,'"$1"."$2"');
return A; 
$$; 
call sp();
```

gives:

| SP |
| --- |
| "Customers"."value" |

If you going to do are fair amount of Javascript it help be helpful to read the [replace doc's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to learn the different match types, then you can hit F12 and use the web browser console to test/debug strings, without having to mash it into a SP and call/run it.